# How to click elements under ng-repeat in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I want to click check box under the repeat, I tried code also but its not working for me-

```
element.all(by.repeater('(spid in spids')).then(function(completeColumns) {
completeColumns[1].click();});
```

`<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="spid in spids"><input class="ng-pristine ng-   valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="spid.isSelected"/ <spanclass="ngbinding"style="padding-left: 10%; font-weight:normal;">wewe</span> </div>`

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat`<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat`="spid in spids"><input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="spid.isSelected"/><span class="ng-binding" style="padding-left: 10%; font weight:normal;">xyz</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `element(by.model('spid.isSelected'))`. It should work.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, Okk will try but if i want to click on checkbox having text "wewe" as u can see in the code there are multiple check box options are there and i want to click multiple check box.